# Change a Django Model with Javascript

Tags: python, html, ajax, django

So i want to change the ***Django Module "Post.upvotes" to +1 everytime*** someone presses the button
without reloading the Page.

***I think its called Ajax***.

***JS:***

```
$('.buttonclass').click(function(){
    var pk;
    pk = $(this).attr("data-pk");
});
```

***html:***

```
<span data-pk="{{post.pk}}" class="buttonclass"></span>
```

***my_views.py***

```
def upvote(request):
    pk = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        pk = request.GET['pk']     
    obj = models.Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    obj.upvotes = obj.upvotes +1
    obj.save()
    return redirect("index") #without this
```

***urls.py***

```
 url(r"upvote/(?P<pk>\d+)/$", views.upvote, name="upvote"),
```

***post:***

```
class Post(models.Model):
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

***So how exactly can i do this?***

Comment: Have you tried looking up how to make an ajax request in javascript? Basically you want a POST (not GET, because you're changing the database) so your view should respond to POST requests. Your ajax call should be to the URL you define for your view, send the `pk` as data and your view should respond with a JSON response so that the script knows if it was successful or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ajax for this issue.

Create a separate route for this URL. (Preferable use post method)

#### my_views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def upvote(request):
    pk = request.GET['pk']     
    obj = models.Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    obj.upvotes = obj.upvotes +1
    obj.save()
    response_data = {'success':1}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

#### your js

```
$('.buttonclass').click(function(){
    var pk = $(this).attr("data-pk");
    $.get('[YOUR_URL_HERE]'+/pk,function (r){console.log(r);})
});
```

Comment: return HttpResponse(json.dumps (...)
Where comes json from?

Comment: HttpResponse simply returns the dict we just created in the json format. Idealy this respose have the count of the post votes. For thr error, check the url you, you must have the trailing slash at the end.